# Lease Accounting / FX Embedded Derivatives

Tags: fx

I have a lease agreement where the functional currency is USD, domestic currency is UAH. Lease agreement is written in EUR (rent rate) and payments are to be done in UAH in the amount of rent rate (EUR) * UAH/EUR exchange rate. Should I account it as an embedded derivative and value separately?

The same question applies to the following situation
I have a lease agreement where the functional currency is USD, domestic currency is UAH. Lease agreement is written in USD (rent rate) and payments are to be done in UAH in the amount of rent rate (EUR) * UAH/USD exchange rate. Should I account it as an embedded derivative and value separately?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Relevant FASB rules are here:http://www.fasb.org/derivatives/issueb21.shtml.
I think you are asking an accoubting question (what are the rules?) not a quant one (how can I model the value of some contract feature?) so this may not be the best forum to ask.